# How to define a decorator that will provide an interpolated doc string for a function/method call

Tags: python, decorator

I'm not good enough with decorators yet to do this ... Is it possible to define a decorator **live_doc** that allows me to get an interpolated doc string after a method or function call, filled in with the actual arguments and return value.

```
@live_doc("f was called with %d, %s and returned %d")
def f(x, y):
  x + len(y)
```

After the code below:

```
f(3, "marty")

d = f.doc
```

**d** should be "f was called with 3, "marty", and returned 8". I would prefer to not build up the strings until f.doc is accessed, but would surely need to squirrel away the call args & return value somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat generalised solution that will treat your original docstring
as a template, and maintain other information about the decorated function
(like its name):

```
from functools import wraps

def live_doc(func):
    template = func.__doc__
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        args_pretty = ", ".join(repr(a) for a in args)
        kw_pretty = ", ".join("%s=%r" % (k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        signature = ", ".join(x for x in (args_pretty, kw_pretty) if x)
        name =  func.__name__
        wrapper.__doc__ = template % locals()
        return ret_val
    return wrapper

@live_doc
def f(x, y):
    """%(name)s was called with %(signature)s and returned %(ret_val)r."""
    return x + len(y)
```

Before `f` is first called, `help(f)` in the interactive interpreter gives you:

```
Help on function f in module __main__:

f(*args, **kwargs)
    %(name)s was called with %(signature)s and returned %(ret_val)r.
```

After it's called, you get:

```
f(*args, **kwargs)
    f was called with 3, 'marty' and returned 8.
```

Or with a more general function, showing off `kwargs`:

```
@live_doc
def q(*args, **kwargs):
    """%(name)s was called with %(signature)s and returned %(ret_val)r."""
    return len(args) + len(kwargs)

>>> q(1, 2, 3, a=7, b="foo")
5
>>> help(q)
q(*args, **kwargs)
    q was called with 1, 2, 3, a=7, b='foo' and returned 5.
```

Obviously you could create whatever variables you wanted to use in the template inside `wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, (and I felt pretty silly writing it, so I might be doing something wrong, especially in the middle part with `t`):

```
def live_doc(d):
    def f_d(f):
        def f_new(*args):
            r = f(*args)
            t = [a for a in args]
            t.append(r)
            t = tuple(t)
            f_new.doc = d % t
            return r
        return f_new
    return f_d

@live_doc("f was called with %d, %s and returned %d")
def f(x,y):
    return x + len(y)

f(1,"hi")
print(f.doc)
// f was called with 1, hi and returned 3
```

I used from http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/ that

```
@decomaker(argA, argB, ...)
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
func = decomaker(argA, argB, ...)(func)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def docme(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        retval = None
        wrap.__doc__ = wrap.__olddoc__ + """

Last called with args: %s, %s
""" % (args, kwargs)
        try:
            retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
            wrap.__doc__ += 'Last returned: %s' % retval
            return retval
        except Exception as exc:
            wrap.__doc__ += 'Failed and raised: %r' % exc
            raise

    wrap.__doc__ = func.__doc__ + '\n\nHas not been called yet'
    wrap.__name__ = func.__name__
    wrap.__olddoc__ = func.__doc__
    return wrap

@docme
def foo(x):
    """foo docs"""
    if x == 1:
        raise ValueError('baz')
    return x * 2
```

It maintains the function's doc string so you can still call `help(foo)` to read its instructions. On every call, it updates that docstring with arguments and result (or the exception it raised):

```
>>> print foo.__doc__
foo docs

Has not been called yet
>>> foo(2)
4
>>> print foo.__doc__
foo docs

Last called with args: (2,), {}
Last returned: 4
>>> foo(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 11, in wrap
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 27, in foo
    raise ValueError('baz')
ValueError: baz
>>> print foo.__doc__
foo docs

Last called with args: (1,), {}
Failed and raised: ValueError('baz',)
```